# Can't tether or hotspot my unlocked AT&T phone with T-Mobile

Tags: tethering, wifi-hotspot, att, t-mobile

I've purchased an unlocked AT&T phone LGE LG-D800

After calling T-Mobile and configuring APN, I can now get 4G. However, I still can't tether. The T-mobile rep said I am out of luck and can't tether with stock tethering application, because it's looking for AT&T servers. He did not way whether a 3rd party app would tether for me, and none of the apps I downloaded worked.

I am thinking, there has to be a way to get it to work: after all, the phone has data, it has wifi, all I have to do is bridge them, right?

I am a Java developer. Never programmed Android but would like to start; so if it comes to that, a programming solution would work.

Surprised with the lack of data on the web! One would think there are lots of people like me!

P.S. I don't care whether the solution involves wifi, USB or Bluetooth.

The error message is as follows:

> ```
> authentication was unsuccessful
> There is a temporary network problem that prevents the
> enablement of the USB tethering function. Please try again later.
> ```

Comment: Are you rooted? There are some xposed modules (http://repo.xposed.info/) for tethering that may work or be adaptable to your specifics.  Have you tried this gem at xda yet? http://forum.xda-developers.com/note-4-tmobile/general/how-to-bypass-t-mobiles-vpn-connection-t2992720

Comment: Just did, same result.  Not rooted but will if i absolutely have to.  It did not ask me about APN protocol and APN roaming protocol, which may be why. Different versions of Android I guess?

Comment: Found a big leap in information here: http://danielpocock.com/android-betrays-tethering-data but it means rooting.  xda is historically the go-to place for good info on rooting - its a large and solid community (and a good place to dip your toe).  If you decide to root, daniel's post above looks like an excellent lead.

Comment: @LivedWithOtters I've read the post and it sounds very straightforward; now I just need to root. As soon as I find the answer to my question here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/101944/how-to-securely-root-g2-phone-att-lge-lg-d800/102033#102033  Perhaps you'd like to take a look? I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: I have to agree with A. Donda's comment on the other post. By the nature of the beast, I don't know that there will ever be a single authoritative source on rooting to consider safe (whatever that really means). In my personal experience, xda forums have been great for both the actual code and the discussions that follow.  Right or wrong, I've made my rooting decisions based on what I found there.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what apps you've tried?  Have you tried [PDANet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pdanet)?

Comment: I have now. Have not tried USB - again, because PDANet has no web of trust, and I am more sensitive about malware on my desktop (the USB option requires windows software install). Wifi does not work.

Comment: Come on guys, I know the bounty does not mean much to you, but I've given half my rep here!