# How to securely root g2 phone (AT&T LGE LG-D800)?

Tags: rooting, root-access, lg, lg-g2

I've been looking to root my phone, only all methods require installing binaries from little-known (by me) sites with no Web of Trust rating. I feel hesitant to do that.

Here are some rooting links I found for my phone:

- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2448887
- http://theunlockr.com/2013/10/25/root-lg-g2-versions-video/
- http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_d800
  requires ioroot: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=48709232&postcount=869

  The latter one refers to Kingo Android Root (its Web of Trust says XDA does not recommend it until it goes open source due to some suspicious activities such as sending IMEI to the server)

Which of them are safer than others?

Also, there was a manual way to root via ADB, or if there was source code, or if there was a reputable trustworthy site to download from, I'd be feeling much more secure.

I am a Java developer, new to Android development, but it' something I want to learn, so programmatic solutions welcome.

Comment: Both XDA developers and Cyanogenmod point to ioroot, and both sources I'd generally consider trustworthy. That being said, afaik there are no hard restrictions for some malicious person to post misleading information on either site. The best you can do is to read through all the comments and trust that if something fishy is happening, someone will find out. Also be aware that you can never be 100% secure when letting some third-party software fiddle with your hardware. – I can't find the reference to Kingo on the ioroot page btw.

Comment: Have you contacted the maintainers of ioroot or Towelroot or Framaroot and asked them if they could please post their source code on GitHub?

Comment: Personally I consider "secure" and "rooted" to be contradictory goals, unless you are an _extremely_ careful sysop.

Answer (score 0):

I used towelroot to root my phone when I was still on a stock ROM. It worked well. There are many other alternatives available as well. I've had no problems with it, and it seems to be what I would consider to be the "safest" as it was designed by geohot, and I've used many of his products in the past.